# some questions about positions in form, css

Tags: html, forms, css

I'm trying to learn HTML & CSS and tried to make a basic login form with CSS3 effects. The link are here below to the code.

Demo - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwaLBE

HTML

```
<form action="" method="">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Användarnamn">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Lösenord"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Logga in">
    <a href="#">Glömt lösenord?</a>
    <a href="#">Registrera</a>
</form>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

form {
    margin-top: 200px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Input text actions */

input[type="text"] {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s;
}

input[type="text"]:hover {
    border: solid 1px #707070;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #969696;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
    border: solid 1px #707070;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #969696;
}

/* Input password actions */

input[type="password"] {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s;
}

input[type="password"]:hover {
    border: solid 1px #707070;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #969696;
}

input[type="password"]:focus {
    border: solid 1px #707070;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #969696;
}

/* Input submit-button actions */

input[type="submit"] {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: -112px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #16a085;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
    border: solid 1px #707070;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #969696;
}

/* Link actions */

a {
    font-size: 12px;
    transition: color 0.5s;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    color: #3498db;
}

a:hover {
    color: #2980b9;
}
```

There are some problems:

1. "glömt lösenord" & "Registrera" are not under the password form to the right. How can I move the links to the right precisely under the form to the right?
2. The "Logga in" button seems to be under the form to the left, but zoom once or twice and the position will change.
   Why do I have `margin-left: -112px;` under the Input submit for? That value looks weird but its their it is under the form to the left.
3. And the last problem, the links "Glömt lösenord" & "Registrera" are in the middle of the button to the left, how can I take them down so they are at the same level as the button to the left?
4. EDIT: If you click on the button, it will take some small amount of time to be clicked, how can I change that time without changing for the inputs?

Comment: when you use bootstrap, you don't need to set your custom margin as in margin-left:-112px; this causes it

Comment: I dont use boostrap. Using only html and css in sublime-text.
How can I fix it only with pure css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEraqb

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

form {
    margin-top: 200px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Input text actions */

input[type="text"] {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s;
}

input[type="text"]:hover {
    border: solid 1px #707070;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #969696;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
    border: solid 1px #707070;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #969696;
}

/* Input password actions */

input[type="password"] {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s;
}

input[type="password"]:hover {
    border: solid 1px #707070;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #969696;
}

input[type="password"]:focus {
    border: solid 1px #707070;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #969696;
}

/* Input submit-button actions */

input[type="submit"] {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: -112px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #16a085;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
    border: solid 1px #707070;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #969696;
}

/* Link actions */

a {
    font-size: 12px;
    transition: color 0.5s;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    color: #3498db;
}

a:hover {
    color: #2980b9;
}
```

1- How can I move the links to the right precisely under the form to the right?

I used a *float:right*

Using [flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) could be another way.

2- zoom once or twice and the position will change.

some sizes was defined in pixel, so it is static and doesn't resists to all layouts.

- About negative margins:
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989930/using-css-negative-margins-a-good-or-bad-practice
  http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

3- And the last problem, the links "Glömt lösenord" & "Registrera" are in the middle of the button to the left, how can I take them down so they are at the same level as the button to the left?

I prefer like that!

4- If you click on the button, it will take some small amount of time to be clicked, how can I change that time without changing for the inputs?

the css animation seems to have to finish before the action occurs.

Comment: I misstook you for placing the 2 links under the button :D

Comment: Gael.
I tried your code and opened in Firefox, it looks like this. --> [link](http://ladda-upp.se/files/2015/b139356.png)
The 2 links are to far right.
[link](http://ladda-upp.se/files/2015/b139356.png)

Comment: I changed the   margin-right: from 1.3% to 13% in .links and got it right, but dont know if that is the right way.

Comment: In firefox on linux, I do not see what you have... I used a calc property, it's almost supported by decent browsers, may be you use an old version?

Comment: changing the margin-right of the links aligns them with the password input, but the problem is that the inputs text should fill more the space

Comment: I think it didnt update when I tried the code, but now I tried again with your code and it looks right. I use the latest version of Firefox (36) on Windows 8.1. It looks good again, The grey #eee color in tha background, it looks like the right part have more space between the border of the grey to the form than on left, its not center or something ..I mean like 1-2px max or something.. Going to see the code again :)

Comment: it hurts me too! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801820/dealing-with-size-in-and-px-for-a-perfect-alignment

Comment: Damn, now it hurts me too. Need to sleep, it's 4AM but hey, need to Google it :)

Answer (score 1):

When you work with a form, it is suggested to wrap it into selector, as in;

body should have value: `margin:0 auto;`

```
#mywrapper{
    margin:0 27%; /*you can set it by yourself*/
    max-width:38%;
}
```

after that, you can wrap the 2 links as follows:

**UPDATED:**

```
span .mylinks{
   float:right;
   padding-right:5px;
}
```

so. it should be like this:

```
<div id="mywrapper">
    <form action="" method="">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Användarnamn" />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Lösenord" />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Logga in" />
        <a href="#">Glömt lösenord?</a>
        <a href="#">Registrera</a>

    </form>
</div>
```

Demo **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Alicera/m4hL6jty/1/)**

Comment: a br is a line break for text, not for styling. Use margin-top instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are many questions, will try to cover it all.

First of all, remove `text-align: center;` on the `<form>` that will make the other tasks easier to solve.

Secondly, add `<p>` or `<div>` etc to wrap your input fields.

Also want to say I love the cleanness of your code, very good start. Don't be afraid to use some classes or ids.

See the blow updated code based on yours, demo - http://jsfiddle.net/78ds0jpt/

HTML

```
<form action="" method="">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Användarnamn">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Lösenord">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Logga in">
        <span>
            <a href="#">Glömt lösenord?</a>
            <a href="#">Registrera</a>
        </span>
    </p>
</form>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

form {
    /* margin-top: 200px; */
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /* text-align: center; */
}

form p {
    margin: 10px;
}

form p span {
    padding-left: 130px;
}

/* Input text actions */

input[type="text"] {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s;
}

input[type="text"]:hover {
    border: solid 1px #707070;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #969696;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
    border: solid 1px #707070;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #969696;
}

/* Input password actions */

input[type="password"] {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s;
}

input[type="password"]:hover {
    border: solid 1px #707070;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #969696;
}

input[type="password"]:focus {
    border: solid 1px #707070;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #969696;
}

/* Input submit-button actions */

input[type="submit"] {
    margin-top: 5px;
    /* margin-left: -112px; */
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #16a085;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
    border: solid 1px #707070;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #969696;
}

input[type="submit"]:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

/* Link actions */

a {
    font-size: 12px;
    transition: color 0.5s;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    color: #3498db;
}

a:hover {
    color: #2980b9;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, know the importance of clean code :-)
In your code, the 2 links are to far right. Can u make them so they are under the right form? I will read more about classes and IDs and see how the correct way to use them are.