# Dealing with size in % and px for a perfect alignment

Tags: html, css

I used the calc property in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28801322/1064270), but I have some troubles to compute the width % of an element with margins, padding and borders set in *px*

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/uL2syf4m/1/):

```
#form {
    margin: 200px auto;
    width: 360px;
    background:green;
    padding:0
}

 input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    width: calc(50% - 42px);
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

There is two inputs. I want that they fill completly their parent div.
My calculation is:

```
100%= (input_width + ( margin_width + padding_width + border_width ) * 2 ) * 2

=> input_width= 50% - 42px
```

but actually, the max width that I can use is *50% - 45px* if I want that the 2 inputs stays at the same line. So What I forgot? [http://jsfiddle.net/uL2syf4m/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/gael/uL2syf4m/3/)

Comment: correct formula is `width: calc(50% - 44px);` - there are four borders by 1px each in horizontal direction.

Comment: 42px is correct - there are only 2 relevant borders on each element.  Interestingly, if you float the two inputs left, and the add `<br style = "clear:both` before the closing div tag, you can use `calc(50% - 42px)` and the inputs align.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not looking for tricks. My problem is theoric.

Comment: Yes, which is why that's not an answer.

Comment: You didn't forget anything - you were just too tidy with your markup.  See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because of the white space created by your markup and how it's treated by `inline-block` elements.  Remove the line break and tabs between your two `input` elements and you can then set `width: (calc(50% - 42px);`.  More details [HERE](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uL2syf4m/5/)

Comment: Yes but this space has really bothered me!

Answer (score 0):

you need to make them float to make it work.

```css
#form {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 360px;
    background:green;
    padding:0
}
#form::before, #form::after{
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

 input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
     float:left;
    width: calc(50% - 42px);
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
    <input type="text" id="input1"/>
    <input type="text" id="input2" />
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uL2syf4m/4/